# How to replace typed bullets with HTML <ul><li>

Tags: excel, replace

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a "description" column. Each description is formatted like this:

```
A sentence about the product.
• A bullet point about the product.
• A bullet point about the product.
• A bullet point about the product.
```

I need to convert all of them to this format instead:

```
A sentence about the product.
<ul>
<li> A bullet point about the product.</li>
<li> A bullet point about the product.</li>
<li> A bullet point about the product.</li>
</ul>
```

Is there some kind of find/replace routine I could use to accomplish this? Or could I bring the text into a different program and then re-import it back into Excel after it is "fixed"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Excel's internal functions to do this. For instance if these values are on A2, place this function to B2 cell;

```
=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("•",A2)-1)&"<ul><li>"&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("•",A2)),"•","</li><li>")&"</li></ul>"
```

It divides the text into two parts from the first bullet and formats like this;
[First part (product description)] + [ul][li] + [Second part (bullets) by replacing bullets with [/li][li] ] + [/li][/ul]

Comment: When I plug this into cell B2 (next to A2, which contains "li" items), it gives me a generic error message: "The formula you typed contains an error".

Comment: @hockey2112 Could you try the formula by using coma; `="<li>" & MID(A2,3,LEN(A2)) & "</li>"`

Comment: Hmmm, getting closer. That formula added an <li></li> wrapper around the entire bulleted list, instead of around each bulleted item: <li> A bullet point about the product  • A bullet point about the product.  • A bullet point about the product.</li>

Comment: @hockey2112 Which means all the items are actually in one cell (A2)? Then it needs bit more work, or at least I don't know an easy way to handle it. If I will have more time later, I will try to look at it.

Comment: Yes, each bulleted list is in an individual cell. Thanks!

Comment: @hockey2112 Could you try this `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,LEFT(A2,3),"<li>"),".",".</li>")`

Comment: That formula results in this (using my example from above). Note how it replaced the word "A" with "<li>":  <li>sentence about the product.</li> 
• A bullet point about the product.</li> 
• A bullet point about the product.</li> 
• A bullet point about the product.</li>

Comment: @hockey2112 Okay, one more time; `=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(".",A2))&"<ul>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(".",A2)),"•","<li>"),".",".</li>")&"</ul>"`

Comment: This formula returned "#VALUE!"

Comment: @hockey2112 I've updated my answer, could you copy the formula from there? I guess this comment section made a change in the formula, when I copied it, I got the same error.

Comment: @hockey2112 Sure, no problem. Good to hear that it helped.

Comment: Serkan, sorry, one other question. In a few of the cells, the first line has more than one sentence. for example, "A sentence about the product. Here is the second sentence.". When that occurs, it places the <ul> between the two sentences. Can your formula be modified to accommodate this?

Comment: @hockey2112 Sorry, I should've mentioned that. It was searching for the first dot to process the sentence. I've updated my answer to search for the first bullet, you can try it again.

Comment: Hotal, that did the trick. One last thing (I think!)... the </li> seems to depend on each line having a period at the end. Any way to make it always place an </li> even if no period exists?

Comment: @hockey2112 Okay, one more update. Now it doesn't use dot at all and relies on bullets. Hope this solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lines are in `A1:A4`, input the following formula in `B2`, and drag down to `B4`:

```
=CONCATENATE("</li>",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"·         ",""),"</li>")
```

Note: Notice that I have multiple spaces after my bullet as I copied it over from MS Word. Adjust it to fit your spacing.

Input the following formula into `C5`:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,CHAR(10),"<ul>",CHAR(10),B2,CHAR(10),B3,CHAR(10),B4,CHAR(10),"</ul>")
```

**Results:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, I tested this one and it looks cool and worked from my end! Thanks again